# Selenium scraping some rows but failing to scrape all rows

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to scrape rows and columns from a website to a csv file. The code I used is working fine but it is providing me only 14 rows out of the total 20 rows. Can someone please help me scrape all the 20 rows.

I am providing the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://app.powerbi.com/home'

browser.get(url)

members = (WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located([By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class,"row ng-star-inserted")]'])))
height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

data = []
while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(1)
    for item in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, "row ng-star-inserted")]'):
        if item.text in data:
            continue
        else:
            data.append(item.text)

    lastheight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if height == lastheight:
        break
    height = lastheight

print(data)
```

I am also providing a screenshot of the page source. All the rows use the same 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZBRI.jpg)

Comment: Hello, is it running headless? If so, maybe make sure the window size is big enough

Comment: I kept running with browser.maximize_window() and only once I got all 20 rows. When I re ran the code, I am back to getting 14.

Comment: It worked when I opened ran the file in a bigger sized monitor but not in my laptop screen.